# How do i replace values in a python dictionary without using long if else statements

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

This is list containing dictionary, the code block works I just want a more pythonic way of achieving this. The code checks if the condition is met and reassign a new value.

```
 for items in waytypes:
        if items['value'] == 1:
            items['value'] = 7
        elif items['value'] == 2:
            items['value'] = 7
        elif items['value'] == 3:
            items['value'] = 4
        elif items['value'] == 4:
            items['value'] = 7
        elif items['value'] == 5:
            items['value'] = 7
        elif items['value'] == 6:
            items['value'] = 10
        elif items['value'] == 7:
            items['value'] = 4
        elif items['value'] == 8:
            items['value'] = 2
        elif items['value'] == 9:
            items['value'] = 1
        else:
            if items['value'] == 10:
                items['value'] = 2
```

Comment: Is there a math rule ?

Comment: It's based on data provider data. Not really a math rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to hold the mapping you want:

```
mapping = {1:7, 2:7} # just complete it
```

And then you will be able to do the conversion based on the mapping:

```
for items in waytypes:
    items['value'] = mapping.get(items['value'],items['value'])
```

As the second param in the `get()` function you can use a default value in case the `items['value']` doesn't exist in your mapping. For example, you can assign the same value in case it doesn't exist in the mapping:

```
mapping.get(items['value'],items['value']) # the value will remain the same.
```

Comment: if you read carefully my solution, I suggested to use `get()` with default value in case the value doesn't exist.

Comment: I got your point but I am not sure that it was the intended behaviour. I will update my answer to let the OP decide if he wants to implement it like that or not. Thank you!

Comment: This wasn't part of the original question I think but anyway you are right. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

you may use a dict:

```
val = {
    1: 7,
    2: 7, 
    3: 4, 
    4: 7,
    5: 7, 
    6: 10, 
    7: 4, 
    8: 2,
    9: 1,
    10: 2}

for item in waytypes:
    if item in val:
        item['value']  = val[item['value']]
```

or:

```
for item in waytypes:
    item['value'] = val.get(item['value'], item['value'])
```

also, you can use a list comprehention:

```
[{**d, 'value': val[d['value']]} if d['value'] in val else d for d in waytypes]
```

Comment: what do you mean? you do not know the full content of the dict item

Answer (score 1):

Make a dictionary to map the before and after values and use that to change the values.

```py
changeValues= {
  1: 7
  2: 7
  3: 4
  4: 7
  5: 7
  6: 10
  7: 4
  8: 2
  9: 1
  10: 2
}

for items in waytypes:
  if items['value'] in waytypes.keys():
    items['value'] = changeValues[items['value']]
```

Comment: @kederrac, I'm assuming the values are between 1 and 10. This is obviously only an example. I'm sure OP can modify it according to their need.

Comment: The whole values are reassigned except those that should remain unchanged